# Python SqlAlchemy + MySql filtering by a JSON column data

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a table *Movies* with a JSON column, defined as:

```
movie_info = Column('movie_info', JsonEncodedDict)
```

Where JsonEncodedDict:

```
class JsonEncodedDict(TypeDecorator):
    impl = Text

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return '{}'
        else:
            return json.dumps(value)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return {}
        else:
            return json.loads(value)
```

Inserting works as expected.
My problem starts when I want to query data and perform filtering on my column.
Suppose I have a record, in which *movie_info* column is:

```
{
    "title": "The Movie - 3",
    "review": "Best movie I have ever seen"
}
```

I would like to query my table and get all records where *review* contains 'best'

I have tried things like

```
session.query(Movies).filter('best' in Movies.movie_info['review']).all()

session.query(Movie).filter('best' in func.json_compare(Movies.movie_info['review'])).all()
```

and several more queries but nothing works.
Any idea would be appreciated

Comment: Why use a TypeDecorator at all, if your MySQL back-end is using its native JSON type? Your updates to this field will be faithfully applied in the ORM, and you only need to flag a record change using `sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.flag_modified` prior to a `commit()`.

Answer (score 6):

That was quick but I found a solution.
I'm not deleting this question, as I've yet to find any answer online so I believe this will be helpful to others.

Using json_extract instead of json_contains:

```
session.query(Movies).filter(func.json_extract(Movies.movie_info, '$.review').ilike('%best%')).all()
```